# git проблема с pull удаленной ветки

Tags: git, github

Сделал git init на удаленном сервере через putty, добавил удаленный репозиторий, делаю pull и стягивается master ветка. А нужна другая конкретная ветка. Как ее задать?

Вот что в конфиг файле git

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "engage.dev"]
    url = https://github.com/my_repository/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/engage.dev/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы с мастера не тянуло указывай

```
git pull origin твояветка
```

Comment: для моего случая git pull engage.dev engage.dev как оказалось. :) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

вводите `git branch -a` и смотрите на ветки, о которых знает git. Они будут выглядеть где то так

```
remotes/origin/branch_1
remotes/origin/branch_2
remotes/origin/branch_3
```

потом пишете `git checkout branch_3` и все будет.

Comment: git branch -a не пишет мне ничего, увы. после выполнения команды выводит строку приглашения.

Comment: git remote show engage.dev выводит мне          engage.dev                  new (next fetch will store in remotes/engage.dev)